# How to let my html canvas can auto detect phone screen and reset its size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I deployed an assign html on my k8s service, but when I open this page by my phone I found it still keep the pc size and can not work fluently. I want to know how to fix this problem.

- I only deploy the index.html on my k8s. Is that the problem?

index.html

```html
<body>


    <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
        <h3>簽字</h3>
        <button onclick="reset()">清空</button>
        <button onclick="restore()">撤銷</button>
        <button onclick="upload()">上傳</button>
        <select class="selectColor" onchange="colorChange(event)">
            <option value="black">黑色</option>
            <option value="red">紅色</option>
            <option value="blue">藍色</option>
            <option value="green">綠色</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id='app'>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="./plugin/canvas-sign.js"></script>
<script>
    let cv = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let rect = document.getElementById("app").getBoundingClientRect();
    cv.width = rect.width;
    // console.log(app.getBoundingClientRect());
    cv.height = rect.height;
    let canvas = new canvasSign(cv);
    let dataJson;
    canvas.on('drawend', (e) => {
        dataJson = canvas.toJson().dataJson;
    })
```

Comment: You can research about Responsive web page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try have your styles as dynamic:

```
let width=Dimensions.get('screen').width
```

or

```
let width=Dimensions.get('window').width
```

same goes with height

Comment: Thank for ur answer,but there is a new problem that I can't use my canvas function to draw now. Any suggest?

Comment: I don't understand, my solution brought about that issue or its just a new random issue you're facing?